# Stop events in $onDestroy method in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm working on a pretty big application in AngularJS and to avoid memory leaks we're implementing the memory release in the `$onDestroy` method, the problem is that there are variables that become `undefined` however, `ng-change` events keep coming from HTML and I have some errors. Is there any way to disconnect all the HTML from the controller? or at least to stop all the events coming from the frontend? I'm working in AngularJS 1.6.

This is an example of how I have defined the components:

```
function requestListController($uibModal, urlRest, $stateParams, $state, uiGridConstants, $filter, httpService) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit= function() {
        // ALL DATA INITIALIZATION
        ctrl.requestListGridOptions.data = [];  

        // GETTING EXTERNAL DATA
        httpService.get(url, true)
           .then(function(response){
                console.log("initRequestList - data.RequestListTO : " , response.RequestListTO);
                angular.copy(response.RequestListTO.requests, ctrl.requestListGridOptions.data);

        }) .catch(function onError(response) {
               // Handle error
               var status = response.status;
               console.log("initRequestList - error : " + status);
        });
    };

    //////////////////////////////
    //                          //
    // on$Destroy method        //
    //                          //
    //////////////////////////////
    ctrl.$onDestroy = function() {
        ctrl.status=undefined;
        ctrl.requestListGridOptions=undefined;
    };

    // OTHER METHODS                
};
//Inject dependencies
requestListController.$inject = [ '$uibModal', 'urlRest', '$stateParams', '$state', 'uiGridConstants', '$filter', 'httpService'];
```

```js
pomeApp.component('requestList', {
    templateUrl: 'request/requestList/requestList.template.html',
    controller: requestListController
});
```

This is more less the structure of my components.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. Disconnect HTML from controller? Controllers are always connected to their HTML. ng-change events don't stop. They can be ignored, but they don't stop until the linked scope is destroyed.

Comment: The example should be **complete**. There should be enough information so that others can reproduce the problem. If the event handlers were properly added to the DOM using AngularJS directives, they will release when the scope is destroyed. The memory leaks are coming from elsewhere.

Comment: Try `ctrl.requestListGridOptions.data.length=0`. That will empty the array without destroying the reference.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you misinterpret the `onDestroy` event. It's mainly to remove timeouts or intervals or events for `$rootScope.$on(...)`.

The ng-change event is bind to the scope. This means it will automatically destroyed if the scope is removed. Therefore the whole scope won't be destroyed and you have another problem.

If you have one big application with one scope or something similar you should use `ng-if` to remove the parts that should not be shown. This will remove the DOM element and with it all the watchers if the variable for `ng-if` is false.

Without any proper code from your side no one can really help you and just make some guesses what your problem could be.

Comment: Hi, maybe as you say I misinterpreted the $onDestroy, the problem is that the scopes don't automatically destroy themselves, and I have a pretty big memory leak. I am working at the component level, I never use rootScope, watcher, timer, I only inject services that help me to manage the system, can the injected services be holding back the destruction of the scope? 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nothing can hold the destruction of the scope back except your Application Structure. There can be only remain some $rootScope watchers and so on but they don't hold the destruction back.
How do you implement your components? Do you have one big single file or do you have multiple sites with different components?
For a good structure you need to use ng-view or ng-if to remove the DOM elements and the binded controller.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to see how many events have been subscribed. Then in the destroy, you can unsubscribe all those events. Sometimes, we also use directives which have to be destroyed. Or there is some logic inside those directives which needs cleanup. Also, if you have subscribed to any events on the root scope, it will live even after a local scope has been destroyed.